# IIS LogonUserIdentity on WindowsAuthentication enabled and impersonation disabled not working

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I've an ASPNET MVC3 application running fine on Forms authentication on IIS10. When I've tried to change to Windows authentication, I want to use LogonUserIdentity.Name to check the username on my own users table but on the first request it's working fine and returning the name of the Logged user on the system but on all other (ajax) requests is returning the IIS User.

What could be wrong? I've searched a lot and verified the following article (https://richhewlett.com/2011/02/15/getting-a-users-username-in-asp-net/) and I've Windows authentication enabled and impersonation disabled (not defined really).

Comment: `.User` of the the controllers is the only place you should use to learn the authenticated users.

Comment: could you please explain what kind of ajax call? some sample code. you could try to use Request.LogonUserIdentity.User. please refer this link for more detail: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.logonuseridentity?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Sorry, I'll delete the question in 2' because I think the problem is on another point with the session and readonly controller.